# How to retain instance when orientation change while communicating with server

Tags: android

in a fragment my app commuicating with webserver now iwant that when orientation changed the fragment retain its instance but its not happening i want every thing remain persistance during orientation changed how is it possible my code is

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);



}
 @Override
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context,R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
    pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
       pDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
       pDialog.setCancelable(false); 
        pDialog.show();
}  
@Override
protected String  doInBackground(Object... params) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if(type.equals("register"))
    {

        /*String url="http://waqasbrosltd.co.uk/index.php/register";
        Network network=new Network();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String registerData=gson.toJson(user);
        try 
        {
            answer=network.registerUser(url,registerData);
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {

        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            closeProgressDialog();
            closeDialogbox();

        }
    }*/

        return null;
}
public void closeProgressDialog()
{

    if (pDialog.isShowing())
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

 iwant my progress dialog also retain its instance but it notr retain
```

Comment: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Comment: This is not a configuration change issue, but rather using the worng pattern for handliung trancations.

Answer (score 0):

When the orientation changes android will destroy all activities and fragments and recreates them again. This is helpful because it also handles resource changes for you. For example if you have different layout file for portrait and landscape mode it automatically switch them for you. 
But you can easily stop this process by handling orientation change yourself. If you do so android will not destroy anything on orientation changes and everything will be persistence. If any resource changes is required you should do it yourself! 
Watch this youtube video to see how to do it 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5J6BURMrHQ&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa

Answer (score 0):

```
In your project manifest.xml inside activity tag put this line 
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

for example:
     <activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>

and override this method in your activity

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

Hope this will help you.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Service`. A `Service` is your way of telling Android that you wanna do something that is not UI-dependant.

The problem is not that your Activities are being destroyed, but rather that you rely on your Activities to handle your communication tasks. This approach is problematic in many other aspects other than orientation change, like when the OS decides to destroy your background `Activity` stacks when in need of resources.

Transactions need to be handled by a `Service`. It is a `Context` object that is not being destroyed by orientation changes, and also refrains Android from shutting down your process when in need of resources.

There is a [great Google IO lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) about implementing REST architecture using an `Activity`, a database and a `Server` object.
Even if you don't implement the whole solution, you can learn a lot from how the lecture addresses this issue.